# Waiting for user input in contructor

Tags: java

Suppose we want to create an object that sets the values of its attributes based on user provided input. Is there any 'danger' in reading from `System.in` in the constructor, rather than doing it before and passing the values as parameters?

Asking just out of curiosity. My concern is the object, whose construction is not yet finished, which can potentially remain in this state for a long time. Would that cause any issues in the multi-threaded environment (I suppose not, as the object is not yet created on the heap). Is there any difference in performance?

Comment: I don't know about safety, but just in terms of proper practice, you shouldn't be doing stuff like taking keyboard input in the constructor anyway in the vast majority of cases. How will you test the object? Taking input in the constructor forces you to manually type in any test data instead of just generating test data by some means and passing it in. You gain nothing by taking input in the constructor, and lose a lot.

Comment: Yes, testability is a very valid argument against doing that, however my question was more targeted to the state of the object and potential safety issues.